# Mkdir combined with "-p" flag

Tags: windows, shell, cmd, flags, mkdir

I am following a tutorial where I have to create a directory but also pass `-p` flag. I tried running it and I got a `syntax failure`. So I wanted to figure out what the `-p`  did and found that this abbreviation is short for [*privileged*](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/options.html). And found

> Script runs as "suid" (caution!)

Started looking what that meant and found it meant Set User Identification and read that

> – When a command or script with SUID bit set is run, its effective UID becomes that of the owner of the file, rather than of the user who is running it. [Source](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/what-is-suid-sgid-and-sticky-bit/)

However, I still do not quite understand it. **What is the purpose of me setting a directory to have that *privilege* and why should I be careful?** Also, I tried looking here but I couldn't find any clarification(with the different search keywords I used). Also, not necessary.. but , why would me doing `mkdir -p src/entities` give me a syntax failure? I am using Windows(but I also have a bash package for Anaconda).

Comment: As far as I know, `-p` means create parent directory if required. Eg. `mkdir -p src/entites` create `src` if not existing.

Comment: What is the error msg that you are getting?

Comment: @dlmeetei ah that makes sense. Yeah, there wasn't a `src` directory yet. So what I researched was completely off then. The error message is `syntax error`, so I just ended up creating the directories seperately. I was just very unsure what the `-p` meant. I'm guessing I don't have my enviroment set up to use `-p` then?

Comment: Not sure of Windows, I was talking about `-p` for Unix, Perhaps, environment issue

Comment: Are you working on Windows or on Unix/Linux? Note that tag [tag:cmd] points to Windows. Please clarify and update the tags accordingly. Thank you!

Comment: I do not think `cmd.exe` produced a message about "suid". Did you copy and paste the error message from the shell into the question?

Comment: @aschipfl I am working with Windows. @lit the error I got  was a  `Syntax Error` Correct, cmd  did not produce that message, I found the "suid" after googling what `-p` was. The tutorial I'm following doesn't use Windows, and was therefore confused what the -p meant. I think my google searches pointed me to different operating systems. I am starting out with this...(sorry if I may have gotten things mixed up with operating systems within my google searches).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're following a Unix-ish tutorial but running the commands on Windows in `cmd.exe`.

As the usage instructions say:

```
C:\>mkdir /?
Creates a directory.

MKDIR [drive:]path
MD [drive:]path

If Command Extensions are enabled MKDIR changes as follows:

MKDIR creates any intermediate directories in the path, if needed.
For example, assume \a does not exist then:

    mkdir \a\b\c\d

is the same as:

    mkdir \a
    chdir \a
    mkdir b
    chdir b
    mkdir c
    chdir c
    mkdir d

which is what you would have to type if extensions were disabled.
```

Windows commands don't use `-` for options (and in particular, the `mkdir` command built into `cmd` doesn't understand `-p`).

---

The part about "privileged" is for the *shell option* `-p`, as in `bash -p`. It has nothing to do with `mkdir -p`, which is explained in [`man mkdir`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mkdir.1.html):

> `-p`, `--parents`
>
> no error if existing, make parent directories as needed

But again, that only applies to the Unix `mkdir`, not Windows / `cmd`.

Answer (score 1):

"-p" creates parent directories if they don't exist.

For example:

With "-p" if "first" directory doesn't exist.

```
mkdir -p first/second  # "first" parent directory is created
```

Without "-p" if "first" directory doesn't exist.

```
mkdir first/second  # "first" parent directory is not created 

mkdir: cannot create directory ‘first/second’: No such file or directory
```